# Как из инпутов (данных в них) создавать объекты

Tags: javascript, объекты, input

Подскажите такую вещь, есть 4 инпута куда нужно вводить инфу, потом  из этой инфы в инпутах, при нажатии кнопки создавать карточки в которых будет то, что ввели в инпуты. Если я правильно понял, нужно создать функцию конструктор. Помогите решить этот вопрос, код ниже. Просто хочу понять как работать с объектами в "реале", ибо если есть похожий пример скиньте или другую информацию.

```
<div class="block-body">
<div class="block-create">
<input class="btn-create" type="button" value="Создать" onclick="create()">
<div class="create">
<form class="create-auto">
<label for="name">Введите наименование</label><br>
<input id="name" type="text"><br>
<label for="mark">Введите Марку</label><br>
<input id="mark" type="text"><br>
<label for="year">Введите год</label><br>
<input id="year" type="text"><br>
<label for="color">Введите цвет</label><br>
<input id="color" type="text"><br>
<input class="continue" type="button" value="Далее" onclick ="cont()">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="list-mark" class="list-mark">
<div id="block" class="block">
<h6>наименование</h6>
<p id="auto-name"></p>
<h6>марка</h6>
<p id="auto-mark"></p>
<h6>цвет</h6>
<p id="auto-year"></p>
<h6>год</h6>
<p id="auto-color"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Стили

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.block-body {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

/* -------------------------------*/ 

.block-create {
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}


.btn-create, .continue {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
}
.btn-create[value],
.continue[value] {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    color:  #4B0082;
    background:#FAEBD7;
    box-shadow:-2px 2px #4B0082;
    outline:none;
}

.create {
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background:lightblue;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:block;
}

.create-auto input:not(.continue) {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    height:25px;
}

/*------------------------------------ */

.list-mark  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#F5FFFA;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    padding:20px;
}

.block {
    width:350px;
    height:250px;
    background:SkyBlue;
    margin:15px;

}

.block h6 {
    color:#F5FFFA;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.block p {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

Код Js что смог придумать

```
var a;

function Car() {
    this.name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    this.mark=document.getElementById('mark').value;
    this.year=document.getElementById('year').value;
    this.color=document.getElementById('color').value;
}

function cont() {
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    div.className="block";
    var listMark=document.getElementById('list-mark');
    listMark.appendChild(div);
    a = new Car();  
}
```

Comment: И что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: не могу понять как с инпутов, записать инфу в дивы которые создаются по нажатию кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
a = new Car();
div.textContent = `Name - ${a.name}, Brand - ${a.mark}, Year - ${a.year}, Color - ${a.color}.`;
```